# Karlov attacking together with a lifelink creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I attack with [Karlov of the Ghost Council](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarlov%20of%20the%20Ghost%20Council%5d) and another creature with lifelink, is Karlov getting 2 counters before he deals his damage this turn? Or are both damages dealt at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All damage is dealt at the same time, so Karlov of the Ghost Council will only get the +1/+1 counters after it has dealt damage.*

> 510. Combat Damage Step
>
> 510.1. First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage, then the defending player announces how each blocking creature assigns its combat damage.
>
> 510.2. Second, all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt **simultaneously**.

*Unless the Lifelink creature also has First Strike or Double Strike

Comment: ...and life gained from lifelink is gained as part of dealing damage ...and Karlov's ability is a triggered ability, which won't be put on the stack, much less resolve, before damage is dealt (i.e. before life is gained).